# Change content on click of button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my scenario goes like this:

I have 3 kind on item to show in div. There are three buttons on top of div and when user click any of the button items corresponding to that items are shown.

Items comes from backend and I am getting all the items loaded on page load as I also need them some where else also within same context.

Currently I am following show hide approach for the same .What I want to know is can there be any other approach that can be better then this in terms of code optimisation. User can also edit /add./remove item?
Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k55jLb48/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('.toggleItems'));
    $('.toggleItems').click(function(){
        $('.containers').hide();  
        var identifier = $(this).data('identifier');
        console.log(identifier);
        $('#'+identifier).show();
    });
})
```

Comment: This show/hide approach is the most common way to do it.

Comment: I think your code is fine. For code reviews consider using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your code looks fine.

Comment: I think this is a good approach, but if number of data become too much you will load all of them?

Answer (score 0):

First order by items then use accordion jquery